# Push in object if value of two parameter do not already exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like below.

```
var obj=[
  { 'Id': 'new_1', 'Name': 'Ticket1', 'TaskId': 'abc', 'ResourceId': '123' },
  { 'Id': 'new_2', 'Name': 'Ticket2', 'TaskId': 'cde', 'ResourceId': '225' },
  { 'Id': 'new_3', 'Name': 'Ticket2', 'TaskId': 'cde', 'ResourceId': '225' },
];
```

Here Id is not unique but the items should be unique on TaskId and ResourceId.

Thatis while pushing into array ,I want to check if similar TaskId and ResourceId exists and if it does dont push else do.

Comment: Cool. So what's giving you trouble? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your object using a for loop like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++)
```

Then, you just check if what you want to push is already inside using an if and brackets to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if the element already exists

```
function push(o) {
    if (!obj.some(function(e) {
        return e.TaskId == o.TaskId && e.ResourceId == o.ResourceId;
    })) {
        obj.push(o);
    }
}

// will not pushed
push({ 'Id': 'new_2', 'Name': 'Ticket2', 'TaskId': 'cde', 'ResourceId': '225' })
// will pushed
push({ 'Id': 'new_2', 'Name': 'Ticket2', 'TaskId': 'cdet', 'ResourceId': '2255' })

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!inArray(obj, newObject)){
    obj.push(newObject);
}

function inArray(array, row){
    for(var i in array){
        if(array[i].Name == row.Name
           && array[i].TaskId == row.TaskId
           && array[i].ResourceId == row.ResourceId){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `for..in` loops on arrays. You're going to end up going over things which aren't elements. Instead, use a standard `for` loop. `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function for checking the existence of things in arrays:

```
function checkAndAdd(item, array) {
  var found = array.some(function (el) {
    return (el.TaskId === item.TaskId
                && el.ResourceId === el.ResourceId);
  });
  if (!found) { array.push(item); return true;}
  return false;
}

var array =[{'Id':'new_1','Name':'Ticket1','TaskId':'abc','ResourceId':'123'},
{'Id':'new_2','Name':'Ticket2','TaskId':'cde','ResourceId':'225'},
{'Id':'new_3','Name':'Ticket2','TaskId':'cde','ResourceId':'225'}];

var newItem = {'Id':'new_1','Name':'Ticket1','TaskId':'abc','ResourceId':'123'};

//return true if the item has been added
var result = checkndAdd(newItem, array);
```